# Compiling Socket Program in C with Windows API on linux using Winelib

Tags: linux, sockets, wine, winelib

I am using winelib to compile a windows socket code in linux platform. My idea is to understand how winelib behaves in the linker stage. I am compiling using two commands "winemaker --lower-uppercase ." and "make" in sequence. Everytime when I do a make the winegcc asks for other headers like "windows.h", "winnt.h" etc. So I have included most of the headers it asks for. My question is, if I need to include the headers then what winelib is exactly doing. Even after including the headers I am getting errors like  "#include nested too deeply" for headers "pshpack8.h" and "pshpack.4".

Even to resolve this I need to use include guards. If I have to do all then what winelib is doing. Or Is there anything wrong with the winelib I am using?

Please help

Comment: The server example from the Windows socket documentation ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/finished-server-and-client-code)) compiles fine with `winemaker . && make` after one minor adaption (changing `#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")` to lowercase ). Answering your question without knowing more specifics about your setup is difficult.